# How to resize canvas in proportion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

There is canvas with background image. Width: 1900px, Height: 1080px
It is necessary to reduce its size to 274 by 120, proportionally.
How can I do it?

Comment: You can't... mathematically speaking, this is impossible. 1900x1080 is an aspect ratio of about 1.76, while 274x120 is an aspect ratio of 2.28. "Proportionally" means "keeping the same aspect ratio", so... that's not possible. Either it won't be proportional, or it won't be 274x120.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk beat me to the punch.  Unless you mean something different by "proportionally" than what the word traditionally means, I think your requirements are not supported by Euclidian geometry...

Comment: If you want to distort an element you can use css transforms on its parent element.